# When using Slick's code generator, how do I filter out columns?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using the Slick codegen tool and filtering out tables and renaming tables and columns successfully. However, how can I skip generating code for unwanted columns?

For example, how would I exclude the `unwanted` column in the `items` table when using `SourceCodeGenerator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude column as follow:

1. Override factory method `Table`.
2. Exclude column from model.
3. Create Table from new model.

E.g:

```
new SourceCodeGenerator(model) {    
  override def Table = model => {
    val columns = 
      if (model.name.table == "items") model.columns.filterNot(column => column.name == "unwanted") 
      else model.columns
    new Table(model.copy(columns = columns)
  }
}
```

Comment: In Slick 3.3.0, this didn't work for me because other parts of the generator still assumed all columns were being generated.

Answer (score 0):

In Slick 3.3.0, I had to override the enabled flag for columns and stop generating code for indices and foreign keys to get this to work:

```
val optDesiredColumns = Map(
    "table_1" -> Set("col_1", "col_2"),
    "table_2" -> Set("col_2", "col_3")
) 

val codegenFuture =  modelFuture.map { m =>
    val model = m
    new SourceCodeGenerator(model = model) {
    override def Table = tableModel => {
        val optDesiredColumns = tableNameToDesiredColumns.get(tableModel.name.table)
        new TableDef(tableModel) {
            override def Column = columnModel => {
                new ColumnDef(columnModel) {
                    override def enabled: Boolean = {
                        val rv = optDesiredColumns.map(desiredColumns =>
                            desiredColumns.contains(columnModel.name)).
                                getOrElse(super.enabled)
                        println(s"***** ${tableModel.name.table}.${columnModel.name} enabled = $rv")
                        rv
                    }
                }
            }

            override def Index = indexModel => {
                new IndexDef(indexModel)  {
                    override def enabled: Boolean = false
                }
            }

            override def ForeignKey = fkModel => {
                new ForeignKeyDef(fkModel)  {
                    override def enabled: Boolean = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```